# Qt and std::string

Tags: qt, stdstring

I have a strange problem. My tool is running properly when I open a file through my Qt file dialog.
However, when I bind dlls from other library into my project in VS 2010, the tool crashes when I open a file. By debugging I discovered that it happens in the destructor of the basic string.
The following line is causing the problem:

```
std::string inputFilename = aFilenames.at(i).toStdString();
```

where aFilenames is a QStringList. If instead I write:

```
std::string inputFilename = "C:\\test.txt";
```

then it works. What is then going wrong with std::string and why this happens when I bind dlls from another library into my project?

Comment: Are you sure that your specific string at location `i` exists? You're not reading somewhere beyond the vector/array?

Comment: I cannot reproduce the problem, you need to provide more information.

Comment: Yes, I am sure that I am not out of bound. I could see it in the debugger. Anyway, if I do not bind the dlls, it works.. . The problem arises when I bind the dlls (third party libraries). But what is the difference between my first statement and the second statement? They are both std::strings...

Comment: @Bart usually when I read out of bound my program gets halted (for QList, that is).

Comment: Try adding debug output, like `qDebug() << aFilenames.at(i);` ... `qDebug() << inputFilename;` and telling what those print.

Comment: Another suggestion, convert string to C string (char array with \0 a the end), and then the C string to std::string (assuming your filename does not have any non-ASCII chars).

Comment: @hyde: this is practically what ruby suggested and it worked. However, I do not understand where the problem was. Was it because of \0 character?

Comment: @ISTB Hard to quess what the problem was without seeing intermediate values (debug output, I mean). It may have been some esoteric character encoding issue related to current default encoding, either at Qt or at STL side.

Comment: Try `QString("C:\\test.txt").toStdString()` instead of c-string in 2-nd example. If that works, `Q_ASSERT(i && (aFilenames.size() > i))` on every iteration just to be sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
string(aFilenames.at(i).toLocal8Bit())
```

Comment: I am not sure, but my windows program has no problem with numerous tests since using it.

Comment: How does `QByteArray` ended as `const char[]`? **upd** (That's just [obvious](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qbytearray.html#operator-const-char--2a), doesn't it?)